# Placing banner above the Bootstrap 3 navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, banner

I have this Bootstrap 3 navbar: http://www.bootply.com/xkcDjvQslb

I want the following modifications:

1. Add banner above the fixed navbar
2. Hide the banner when I scroll down

I saw the following example: http://www.bootply.com/69848; not great at bootstrap and when I pull the relevant code it breaks my menu.

The banner (above the navbar) would be a table with a logo on the left side and title on the right.
I need someone to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/541/ , just needed to clean up my code:

```
topnavbar {
    margin: 0;
}
#topnavbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#banner {
     background-color: yellow;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove navbar-fixed class in nav.  Then place markup above the nav.

http://www.bootply.com/vxJEiv1RC2

Comment: No bootstrap with this one, just JQuery.