# How to add banner above navbar-fixed-top with bootstrap and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm making my first website by PHP with AngularJS and Bootstrap.
I want to add a banner above a navbar-fixed-top. Means:
when on top:

> --------------
>
> banner
>
> --------------
>
> navbar
>
> --------------
>
> body
>
> --------------

when scrolling:

> --------------
>
> navbar
>
> --------------
>
> body
>
> --------------

I have looked for several methods but them seem didn't work.
Thank you :D

Comment: This here might help:
[Placing banner above the Bootstrap 3 navbar?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209336/placing-banner-above-the-bootstrap-3-navbar

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work :(